# Trying to update user in devise, having issues when the form is rendered outside of registrations/edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm trying to update my user from a different view than the default registration/edit view.  I haven't set the form up all the way yet, but i'm having routing issues to begin with.

This is my form:

```
%section#profile-editor
    .row
      .small-12.columns
        %h2 Edit Profile
    .row
      .small-12.columns
        .well
          =form_tag(edit_thing_registration_path,method: 'PUT', id: "my-awesome-dropzone.dropzone") do 
            .row
              .small-4.columns
                %input#photo-dropzone{:name => "file", :type => "file"}/
              .small-8.columns
                .row
                  .small-12.columns
                    %label{:for => "Name"} Name
                    %input{:name => "Name", :type => "text"}/
                  .small-6.columns
                    %label{:for => "Website"} Website
                    %input{:name => "Website", :type => "text"}/
                  .small-6.columns
                    %label{:for => "Itunes"} Itunes URL
                    %input{:name => "Itunes", :type => "text"}/
                  .small-6.columns
                    %label{:for => "Video"} Youtube Video URL (For Profile)
                    %input{:name => "Video", :type => "text"}/
                  .small-6.columns
                    %label{:for => "Email"} Admin Email
                    %input{:name => "Email", :type => "text"}/
            .row
              .small-12.columns.pad-top
                %label{:for => "RTE"} Content
                %input.jqte{:name => "input", :type => "text", :value => ""}/
            = submit_tag "Submit", class: "button button-green"
```

This is my route:

```
devise_for :things, controllers: { registrations: "things/devise/registrations", sessions: "things/devise/sessions"}
```

Controller:

```
class things::Devise::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def update
    # For Rails 4
    account_update_params = devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update)
    # For Rails 3
    # account_update_params = params[:user]

    # required for settings form to submit when password is left blank
    if account_update_params[:password].blank?
      account_update_params.delete("password")
      account_update_params.delete("password_confirmation")
    end

    @user = thing.find(current_thing.id)
    if @user.update_attributes(account_update_params)
      set_flash_message :notice, :updated
      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case their password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
       redirect_to thing_path(@user)
    else
      render "edit"
     end
  end
```

What happens when I click submit:

```
No route matches [PUT] "/things/edit"
```

Rake routes:

```
               new_thing_session GET    /things/sign_in(.:format)                      things/devise/sessions#new
                  thing_session POST   /things/sign_in(.:format)                      things/devise/sessions#create
          destroy_thing_session DELETE /things/sign_out(.:format)                     things/devise/sessions#destroy
                 thing_password POST   /things/password(.:format)                     devise/passwords#create
             new_thing_password GET    /things/password/new(.:format)                 devise/passwords#new
            edit_thing_password GET    /things/password/edit(.:format)                devise/passwords#edit
                                 PATCH  /things/password(.:format)                     devise/passwords#update
                                 PUT    /things/password(.:format)                     devise/passwords#update
      cancel_thing_registration GET    /things/cancel(.:format)                       things/devise/registrations#cancel
             thing_registration POST   /things(.:format)                              things/devise/registrations#create
         new_thing_registration GET    /things/sign_up(.:format)                      things/devise/registrations#new
        edit_thing_registration GET    /things/edit(.:format)                         things/devise/registrations#edit
                                 PATCH  /things(.:format)                              things/devise/registrations#update
                                 PUT    /things(.:format)                              things/devise/registrations#update
                                 DELETE /things(.:format)                              things/devise/registrations#destroy
```

Comment: What's the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: Added rake routes output

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to render devise forms from any controller you should put this in your application helper:

```
 def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a url that maps to a GET request in your form: `edit_artist_registration_path`. Instead, you'll want the url of the form to point to the `PUT` or `PATCH` url for artist registration:

```
form_tag(artist_registration_path, method: 'PUT', id: "my-awesome-dropzone.dropzone")
```